# Visual Studio 2022 React and ASP.NET Core + Vite and Docker Compose

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, docker-compose, vite

Disclaimer: Potential Noob Question - I might have misunderstood something very fundamental!

I have created a new website using Visual Studio 2022 Professional. I have used the template `React and ASP.NET Core - Typescript". This creates a solution with two projects. A server application in .NET 8.0 (LTS) and a client project that is a react frontend with Vite support. A sample endpoint exposes random weather forecast data and this is visualized in the React App.

When I press F5 two browser windows open up. One with the API spec (Swagger) and one with the react app. Vite is started using `npm run dev`.

Now I want to change this to run using Docker compose. This is so I can run a SQL Server 2022 in a container of its own and start developing endpoints that expose data from a database. I right click on the server project and select "Add"/"Container orchestration support".

But I never get this far. Once I have added container orchestration support, the Vite server doesn't start again. When I press F5 only the swagger definition appears.

What am I missing here? Why doesn't Vite start? I can't navigate to https://localhost:5173/

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? Should I not use Docker compose at all? Is it a wrong approach to want to get the SQL 2022 dev server up and running in Docker compose? Or is there a simple checkbox I just forgot to check?

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting, I think I found a solution.

Instead of running my frontend app in a container, I configured my solution to have multiple startup projects. The two projects are docker-compose and my front end client. That starts up both browsers on F5.

Another perk of using docker compose is that I can map the port of the API to a static port, so it doesn't change on every startup, and I can map the API target in my vite.config.ts.